# Host an Active Directory from AWS EC2 and sync users from Azure AD

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, azure-active-directory

Is it possible to sync users from Azure AD to AWS AD going to `EC2` also? I have created users with Office365 license in Microsoft and also our domain. Azure is a bit expensive on their monthly cost. There's this called `AWS SSO`. It's just I don't get how `SSO` works. Do I need to move every single users from Azure AD to AWS SSO then create an `EC2` instance there?

What I want is to create an `EC2` instance where the Active Directory goes and sync users from Azure AD towards it. Are there any other ways to do this? I'm new to using AWS actually.

Comment: Hope this helps : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/azure-ad-idp.html

Comment: Will read this thoroughly. Thanks! @ShivkumarMallesappa

Answer (score 0):

To configure Azure AD integration with AWS, make sure to have these subscriptions: ***An Azure AD subscription and An AWS SSO-enabled subscription.***

Initially, add AWS from Gallery to list of Saas apps in Azure AD. To do that, follow below steps:

- ***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure AD -> Enterprise Applications -> Select all applications -> Add an application -> Select new application.***
- ***Search for AWS in "Add from Gallery" section.***
- ***Select AWS and add the app.***
- ***Go to properties -> Copy Object ID value.***

**To configure AWS SSO, please find below steps:**

- Sign into AWS website as admin.
- Select AWS Home icon -> AWS Services pane -> Under **Security, Identity & Compliance**-> Select **IAM (Identity & Access Management)**.
- On left pane -> Select Identity Provider -> Select Create Provider
- In Configure Provider pane, choose required details.
- On the **Verify Provider Information** pane, select **Create**.
- select **Roles**, and then select **Create role**.

To know more in detail, please find below **reference**:

[Tutorial: Azure Active Directory integration with Amazon Web Services to connect multiple accounts | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/aws-multi-accounts-tutorial#prerequisites)).